# Ethers are withdrawn using send from source contract but not received in account

Tags: solidity, contract-debugging, multisignature

I am trying to send ethers using the following code:

```
//check if confirmed by both the owners
if(tr.confirmedByUbuntu && tr.confirmedByWindows) {
    bool withdrawal = tr.to.send(tr.value); //Send the ethers
    if(withdrawal) {
        ConfirmedTransaction(_confirmationHash, tr.to, tr.value, tr.data);
        delete pendingTransactions[_confirmationHash];  //Free up the storage on EVM
    } else {
        TransactionConfirmationFailed(_confirmationHash, tr.to, tr.value, tr.data);
    }
}
```

The line where I am sending ethers, does withdraw ethers from the source contract but does not deposit in target account. I am doing it on a private network. In what scenarios can this happen? In case of send failure we should we would get the withdrawal result as false but I get that as true.

Full source code is at: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/e4fdac24643c7146a04bd9b3d96fbb4c

Comment: What kind of target you are sending to? Another contract? Account? How do confirm if the target receives ETH?

Comment: I am sending ethers to an account. I checked the target account in mist wallet.

Comment: Are the wallet and the contract in the same network? Please confirm the transaction with blockchain explorer.

Comment: Yeah, I have 2 laptops running on the same private network. I made them peers using admin.addPeer(). I had miner running on 1 of them. Let me check the transaction using block explorer. will be back in a while.

Comment: Try to check the transaction id at least with two independent applications

Comment: Smells like the transaction doesn't propagade in your private network and network misconfiguration.

Answer (score 1):

There is a known issue when you have a private network with only one miner. Even if your network is 'properly' configured your transaction will not propagate from the non-mining node to the mining node and therefore will never be included in a block.

You need to mine with both nodes so that your transaction can be included in a block.